# GMC c5500 TopKick

Tags: transmission, obd-ii, electronic-control-module, gmc, topkick

There is a transmission problem and a code on this truck but my scanners cannot read the PCM codes. What scanner should I use to read PCM codes on a GMC c5500 TopKick?[image]

Comment: What year is your TopKick?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 It is a 2008 model.